# Photo viewer / File Manager thumbnails / photos

Tags: thumbnails, photo

I started working @ a recovery data company and sometimes I have to manualy go through all the photo's and delete the ones that are not 100% correct.

Something the thumbnail shows no problem with the picture, but when I open it, it's totally messed up. And it would safe me A LOT of time if there's a program or a file manager kind of thing that shows the photo in a small size instead of showing the thumbnail, since thumbail isn't the same as a small picture.

Hope you all understand and someone has a good solution.

Thanks <3

Comment: smaller size will imply a different image too. What's the issue with thumbnails? Did you try open them with let's say shotwell?

Comment: THanks for your reply. The thing is with thumbnails, the thumbnail picture doesnt show there isn't any damage in the photo but when I open the photo, it's totally damaged (damaged as in weird colors and halfway cut off). So thumbnail doesnt show me the actual information/picture of the photo.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The thumbnail may have been derived from the photo before it was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your images using `feh`

```
sudo apt-get install feh
```

Open a terminal and try the thumbnail mode in your Pictures folder:

```
feh -t
```

> feh is an X11 image viewer aimed mostly at console users. Unlike most
>   other viewers, it does not have a fancy GUI, but simply displays
>   images. It is controlled via commandline arguments and configurable
>   key/mouse actions.

Visit: http://feh.finalrewind.org

Comment: thanks, I will try this asap I get my hands on a harddrive with broken photos again, thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing the thumbnail cache before you open the folder.
Run these commands:

```
rm -r ~/.thumbnails
killall nautilus
```

This will regenerate the thumbnails again with the defects (hopefully). Then in Nautilus, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in on the thumbnails for a clearer larger view. Then you can select and delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: thanks, I will try this asap I get my hands on a harddrive with broken photos again, thanks again for the tip.